# What is bandwidth demand?

Tags: performance, memory-management, language-agnostic, distributed-computing, bandwidth

What does bandwidth demand mean?
I've seen it being used in this paragraph:

> "Memory must be distributed among the processors rather than
>   centralized; otherwise the memory system would not be able to support
>   the **bandwidth demands** of a large number of processors without
>   incurring long access latency"

Answer (score 2):

In this case, "bandwidth demand" refers the amount of memory bandwidth a large distributed application needs. It mainly refers to the combined amount of traffic between the nodes in the system.

---

Consider a city with streets and roads. Every day, people need to get to and from work. The total number of people who need to get from point A to point B is the **bandwidth demand**.

Depending on the size of the city, this can be a very large number.

*What would happen if you made everyone work in the same place?*

Each morning, everybody gets up and converges on the same "work district". What's the result?

## Traffic!

[image]

<sub>Image by NOMAD, from Wikipedia Commons: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Trafficjamdelhi.jpg</sub>

Everybody gets stuck in traffic and they take forever to get to work (high access latency).

---

A distributed computing system isn't too different from a city. If you don't distribute your memory correctly, you will have bandwidth congestion on certain channels in the network.

For example, if all your data is concentrated on node X and all the other nodes need to access that data, you will overwhelm all the data channels going to and from node X.

On the contrary, a better designed system will distribute the data evenly across the network and close to the processors that will use them. This cuts down on traffic congestion by shortening commute times and splitting up the traffic over all the channels rather than just one or a few.

---

The point that the quote is saying is that you need to properly distribute memory in order to satisfy the high bandwidth demands of the application.